# How do I install Steam after this error? Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, steam, lxde, chromebook

Attempting to get steam on my Chromebook has been a real headache.

When I double click the Steam Icon Package Installer opens and says:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
```

I enter my password and it fails sends me a long error ending with

```
E: Package 'package name' has no installation candidate
```

(There is one line of these for each package mentioned above)

When it closes it says I am missing the following 32-bit binaries, and Steam may not run : libc.so.6

```
System Information:
Samsung Chromebook
uname -rm
3.8.11 armv7l
```

Answer (score 1):

try following in terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install steam -f
```

Comment: That input gave me this result: E: Package 'steam' has no installation candidate

Comment: @YamaSultani can you provide full output for following commands: 

`1) $ uname -a`
`2) $ sudo apt-get install steam -f`

Comment: Output for 1: Linux localhost 3.8.11 #1 SMP Sun Jun 21 16:22:31 PDT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux                   Output for 2: Reading Package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done Package steam is not available, but is referred to by another package This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the following packages replace it: steam-launcher E: Package 'steam' has no installation candidate

Comment: @YamaSultani sorry for late response. but, as for me - You are not using ubuntu (maybe debian) and you have processor armv7 !? what pc do you have or its android (chrome os). also, in your packages *steam* is not present. one more output then, plz:  `$ lsb_release -a`

Comment: @YamaSultani UPDATE. now i see. i have look on your prime post )) so, you have Chrome OS (btw: try CHROMIXIUM). you should dowanload `steam` from [valve site](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux) OR [steam wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve#Installation)